# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' LAN network

Tags: vb.net

I made a TreeView that show all users on my LAN network and everything work.

- when I click on any user it show the IP and PCname without any problem, but
- when I click on the main network "HomeGroup" I get this message below

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll

**And highlight this line:**

With System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(CompName)

```
Function GetIPAddress(ByVal CompName As String) As String
    Dim oAddr As System.Net.IPAddress
    Dim sAddr As String
    Try
        With System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(CompName)
            oAddr = New System.Net.IPAddress(.AddressList(0).Address)
            sAddr = oAddr.ToString
        End With
        GetIPAddress = sAddr
    Finally
    End Try

End Function
```

**UPDATE**

```
 Function GetIPAddress(ByVal CompName As String) As String
    Dim oAddr As System.Net.IPAddress
    Dim sAddr As String
    Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        With System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(CompName)
            End
            oAddr = New System.Net.IPAddress(.AddressList(0).Address)
            sAddr = oAddr.ToString
        End With
        GetIPAddress = sAddr
    Finally
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: You probably pass an invalid value in `CompName` when you click an item in the tree that's not a user.

Comment: yea well, a homegroup is not a 'device', it doesnt have an ip does it now..

Comment: ya that's exactly my problem, the next step is to add users to specific groups, and as what you said homegroup or other groups not have IP, how i can solve that? or at least ignore nodes that not have any IP?!

Comment: @narzan one option is to add a `catch` clause and check what socketexception you receive and base your action on the result. another solution would be to set a node type "user" or "group" to your list nodes, and only call the function if you click on a "user" type node.

Comment: second solution will make problems in future If i want add broadcast to group, I like the first one, can i have a hint about the first solution, to make my own research :)

Comment: @narzan 2nd solution will not make problems if you manage the users/groups correctly. about the first solution, it is as simple as it sounds, you add a `catch` clause and base your action on the exception you catch. have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx)

Comment: that's solve the problem :) thanks, but now no IP ?! look at my question to see the last update

Comment: @narzan you misunderstood the whole point, you get an exception when you click the homegroup. so in the catch clause you only handle the homegroup scenario

Comment: Let me read it again then hmm ...

Comment: Ok now i understand after I tried everything with Catch, I want to use the second method seems more realistic for me, please give me more hints about the second method

Comment: @narzan i dont know how you populate your treeview so i cant be more specific, but in general what you need to do is to populate the tree with objects, not just strings. and each object should have a type attribute. and then when you click one of them, check what is the type of the item you clicked and if its user then call the get ip function.

Comment: I want to cry right now ... I don't know how i will make all that, anyway thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example in VB.NET Forms application.

i have added comments in the code but if you have more questions, feel free to ask:

```
Public Class Form4

    Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'an array of predefined users, for testing purposes. 
        'you can use your LAN users instead.
        Dim USR_Array() As String = {"user1", "user2", "user3"}

        'first add a homegroup node, you can add yours.
        Dim mainNode As New TreeNode()
        'name of the node will hold the node type, GROUP in this case
        mainNode.Name = "GROUP"
        mainNode.Text = "HomeGroup"
        Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(mainNode)

        'loop through the user list and add them as well
        For Each USR In USR_Array
            Dim usrNode As New TreeNode()
            'the name of those nodes will be USER to represent
            'the type of those nodes
            usrNode.Name = "USER"
            usrNode.Text = USR
            mainNode.Nodes.Add(usrNode)
        Next USR
    End Sub
    Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
        'after select, check if it was performed by a mouse click
        If e.Action = TreeViewAction.ByMouse Then
            Select Case e.Node.Name
                Case "GROUP"
                    MsgBox("Group node clicked")
                Case "USER"
                    MsgBox("User node clicked")
                    'call the GetIPAddress function here
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```